# How do I update user information on database with a background job for a Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron-task, infusionsoft

I am currently trying to update a user's information with the use of the Heroku scheduler add-on. My function is configured to run every 24 hours and check which users 14-day free trial has ended, then automatically remove upgrade their account to a paid version. My function runs as it should and updates a user's information but only updates the user's information after the user logs in to my app again.

So my question is how would I go about creating a background process to update a users information without requiring them to log in to my Heroku app for their fields to be updated?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what have you tried?  Seems like a rake task would do the job.  Have the Heroku scheduler run the rake task to update the database every 24 hrs.

Comment: @Ren Yeah thats what I thought too but it doesn't update the user until they sign in again. I should mention that there is a client and server side to my app, both of which are hosted on heroku. I had the heroku scheduer on my client side app, do you think I should use it on the server side?

Comment: oh i see.  Yes the server side is what you want